# ERR_INVALID_SIGNED_EXCHANGE error in Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I've set up my simple website with valid **Let's Encrypt SSL** certificate (from **certbot**). My [nginx config](https://github.com/wmnnd/nginx-certbot/blob/master/data/nginx/app.conf) is very short and trivial.

Website shows up correctly in latest Firefox. It shows 404 page, which is OK to me and should work as expected: 404 page.

If I try Google Chrome, i get an error:

> The webpage at https://example.org/ might be temporarily down or it
>   may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_INVALID_SIGNED_EXCHANGE

I [assume](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2381978?hl=en) that the `application/signed-exchange` header may cause this.

What is this header and should i remove it from response?

Request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
DNT: 1
example.org example.org
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2019 12:05:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Content-Length: 345
Connection: keep-alive
```

What to fix?

Comment: What kind of strange Content-Type is this in the response from the server? It should be a single type only and not a combination of types. It looks like your server simply reflects what the client sends as `Accept` which is a broken behavior. And this might actually be the source of your problem according to [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2381978?hl=en).

Comment: as you can see, this is standard nginx 404 reply (config file is linked in my question)

Comment: @Croll Did you manage to solve this issue? If yes then may I ask how ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` in the response is incorrect. It should be a single type, [as Steffen Ullrich said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417266/err-invalid-signed-exchange-error-in-google-chrome#comment97556077_55417266). For a 404 page, I suspect you want `Content-Type: text/html`.

This may be something particular to your nginx config. On my server, 404 pages have `Content-Type: text/html`.